# How to configure alerts in Prometheus for diskspace

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

We have prometheus running on Win Server box, and WMI exporter on a separate box(client). 
Able to read client metrics in Prometheus. Now the requirement is the moment Diskspace =>90 % , send an email alert, so that we can run a job to clean up space using an automated job / manual job.

Could you please help on how to configure alert for diskspace >90

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to set up alerts in general, or do you just need suggestions for what query to use as the basis for the alerting rule?

Answer (score 7):

You might want to alert based on if it's going to fill up, not based on how full it is:

```
- name: node.rules
  rules:
  - alert: DiskWillFillIn4Hours
    expr: predict_linear(node_filesystem_free{job="node"}[1h], 4 * 3600) < 0
    for: 5m
    labels:
      severity: page
```

https://www.robustperception.io/reduce-noise-from-disk-space-alerts

Comment: Use of `for: 5m` good practice as this should avoid false positives where disk usage spikes but levels off i.e. backup clear down / creation

Comment: 5m combined with 1h isn't that good, I still get alerts for spikes that then resolve themselves

Answer (score 5):

assuming you are using https://github.com/martinlindhe/wmi_exporter/blob/master/docs/collector.logical_disk.md you could use something along these lines for > 90 % use

```
  - alert: DiskSpaceUsage
expr: 100.0 - 100 * (wmi_logical_disk_free_bytes / wmi_logical_disk_size_bytes) > 90
for: 10m
labels:
  severity: high
annotations:
  summary: "Disk Space Usage (instance {{ $labels.instance }})"
  description: "Disk Space on Drive is used more than 90%\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}\n  LABELS: {{ $labels }}"
```

there are other examples on wmi_exporter repo
for default node_exporter metrics ( not sure if available with windows ) it should be

```
- alert: DiskSpace10%Free
     expr: 100 - (100 * node_filesystem_avail_bytes / node_filesystem_size_bytes) > 90
     labels:
       severity: moderate
     annotations:
       summary: "Instance {{ $labels.instance }} is low on disk space"
       description: "diskspace on {{ $labels.instance }} is used over {{ $value }}% ."
´´´
```

Answer (score 2):

To send email notification based on alert you need to setup alertmanager with prometheus. Here is the guide how to do that: https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager

Also you can configure the alert rules. I am using node exporter to fetch node metrics and using the following rule

```
- alert: DiskSpace10%Free
     expr: node_exporter:node_filesystem_free:fs_used_percents >= 90
     labels:
       severity: moderate
     annotations:
       summary: "Instance {{ $labels.instance }} is low on disk space"
       description: "{{ $labels.instance }} has only {{ $value }}% free."
```

You can configure the above rule according to WMI exporter and you will be good to go. Hope this helps.

Comment: Presumably you are using some sort of custom metric here `node_exporter:node_filesystem_free:fs_used_percents` is not a core metric. You give no explanation about that. Perhaps you could?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.leanxcale.com/leanxcale/1.5/installation_admin/monitoring/index.html#alerting-rules-recording-rules

```
   groups:
      - name: recording_rules
        interval: 5s
        rules:
          - record: node_exporter:node_filesystem_free:fs_used_percents
            expr: 100 - 100 * ( node_filesystem_free{mountpoint="/"} / node_filesystem_size{mountpoint="/"} )
    
      - name: alerting_rules
        rules:
          - alert: DiskSpace10%Free
            expr: node_exporter:node_filesystem_free:fs_used_percents >= 90
            # Note that previous expression evaluates the metric defined in the recording rule.
            labels:
              severity: moderate
            annotations:
              summary: "Instance {{ $labels.instance }} is low on disk space"
              description: "{{ $labels.instance }} has only {{ $value }}% free."
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.