# Is there a way to set up alert with Prometheus storage retention size

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

Is there a way to set a prometheus alert on `storage.tsdb.retention.size`, lets say if the retention size has been hit, i want an alert sent out.

Comment: I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further.

Answer (score 0):

- As per the [prometheus operational flags](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/command-line/prometheus/) `--storage.tsdb.retention.size flag` is **set to the maximum number of bytes that can be stored for blocks and cannot set alerts for this** . The  supported units to set retention size are : B, KB, MB, GB, TB, PB, EB. Ex: "512MB". Based on powers-of-2, 1KB is 1024B. Use this with server mode only.
- As the alert configuration is unable to be set, you can use this flag  `--storage.tsdb.retention.time:` to remove old data. By this make sure storage is free.  This retention time defaults to 15d. Units Supported: y, w, d, h, m, s, ms. Use this with server mode only.

  **Example** : `--storage.tsdb.retention.time=2h` - erases old information after 2 hours. This is the lowest supported retention time.
- As this is a valid request you can take help/support from this [prometheus official site](https://discuss.prometheus.io/) or raise a git issue under the [prometheus git community](https://github.com/prometheus-community).
- If you need to configure the prometheus alert for disk usage then use the `node_filesystem_avail_bytes` flag. Refer to this [How to configure alerts in Prometheus for diskspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52843351/) by Abraham Dhanyaraj Arumbaka.

Comment: prometheus exposes `prometheus_tsdb_retention_limit_bytes` which is the "Max number of bytes to be retained in the tsdb block" and `prometheus_tsdb_storage_blocks_byte` which is "he number of bytes that are currently used for local storage by all blocks". I guess you can alert on those. I may miss the point because blocks will get deleted whenever you reach the maximum size and that's the purpose of this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about `storage.tsdb.retention.size`, but another way to accomplish this is to create an alert rule for prometheus persistent volume being used as storage.

The example below would be triggered if disk usage > 90%:

```
      - alert: HighDiskUsageOnPVC
        expr: 100 * sum(kubelet_volume_stats_used_bytes) by (persistentvolumeclaim)/sum(kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes) by (persistentvolumeclaim) > 90
        for: 1m
        labels:
          severity: warning
        annotations:
          summary: High disk usage on Persistent Volume {{ $labels.persistentvolumeclaim }}
          description: "More than 90% of the disk was used."
```